# can't correctly create symfony 5 postgres database when using pdo_pgsql driver

Tags: php, mysql, database, postgresql, symfony

I'm tring to use postgres whi symfony 5 and php 7 on windows 10 .

in my env file :

> DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:1234@127.0.0.1:5432/dbtest?serverVersion=12&charset=utf8"

I get could not find driver .

currelty in my php.ini file :

```
...
extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pdo_sqlite
extension=pgsql
```

so i tried this database url

```
DATABASE_URL="pdo_pgsql://postgres:1234@127.0.0.1:5432/dbtest?serverVersion=12&charset=utf8"
```

doctrine.yaml conf :

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'

        # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
        # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
        #server_version: '13'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: Ap
```

after  : php bin/console d:d:c

i get :

[image]

i don't understand this behavior

The database url is taken as a database name in phpmyadmin

The database should be a postgres database so why i see the dabase under phpmyadin ?

I will be really gratful if some explain this to me !

Comment: What is actually the problem? `I get` is not proper issue description, especially when UI is not in English

Comment: thank you for your question,  UI is not in english ?     my problem is tha databse should be a postgres database, so i don't understand why i see the database in phpmyadmin ?  and the other question why all the database_url is used as database name ?

Comment: Do you have any other `.env*` file? Doesn't make sense to me that it creates a database **in mysql**. And this kind of problem usually arise because there are several `php.ini` files, depending on the SAPI used (cli vs mod_php vs php-fpm), the driver could not be active in the cli one.